# GNU GCC Compiler: cpp.exe -v Command Contains an Error with result when displayed! Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise and this Fatal Error is included with a result when executing a command which is below!

`cpp.exe -v`

This command result contains a fatal error which is below:

cpp: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: It means your installation is incomplete or incorrect.  I'd probably uninstall and reinstall the compiler.  However, I'm not a Windows user.

Comment: Assuming Mingw, it usually requires that you add the mingw64\bin directory to the PATH. Possible duplicate: [Run MinGW gcc compiler in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489329/584518). Or you could just use a modern IDE such as Codeblocks, instead of 1990s command line.

Comment: Do I need to install 64bit version of MingW? I have the 32bit version of MingW.

Comment: Could I have both versions installed or only One Version?

Comment: I do have this folder in the PATH system environment variables!

Comment: Issue Solved! I need to make sure that the Environment Variable GCC_EXEC_PREFIX is not an Environment Variable or that It is Correctly Configure Crucial Configuration of this Variable Is a mandatory step so that this fatal error does not occur!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: So I can't add info to the question with detailed information that would solve the problem, that way Anyone else who has a problem similar to this problem could solve it because I found the solution to solve the issue.