# I am inputting a double integer into an equation, but keep getting 0

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C programming and am running into a little issue.

I am inputting 0.05 as a double float and am running it through the formula given in my solution picture to acquire the answer 0.06242. However, I keep getting 0.000000 no matter what I type as my input. Can someone explain to me if there is something wrong with my code or maybe explain if I am using "%lf" correctly in both scanf and printf? Thanks.

[image: Solution to my problem]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
    double guess, pow1,pow2,pow3, estimate;
    printf("Type in an initial guess of the root(for this case type 0.05):  ");
    scanf("%lf", &guess);

    printf("Calculating the root estimate using formula from solution...\n");
    pow1 = pow(guess, 3);
    pow2 = 0.165*pow(guess, 2);
    pow3 = 3*pow(guess, 2);

    estimate = guess - ((pow1 - pow2 + 0.0003993) / (pow3 - 0.33*guess));
    printf("Estimate = %lf\n", estimate);
}
```

Comment: Debug the code line by line and see where the value is going wrong

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://onlinegdb.com/ByAawn_Lr)

Comment: Try to split your complex expressions and calculations into smaller and simpler ones. For example `3*pow(guess, 2)` could be done as `double temp = pow(guess, 2); pow3 = 3 * temp;`. That way it will be much easier for you to see intermediate results when *debugging* to see where the error might be.

Comment: What is a "double integer"?

Comment: Tip: Whenever you are unsure if your input method is correct, replace it with hardcoded values and see if you get the same results. For example, replace `scanf("%lf", &guess);` with `guess = 0.05;`.

Comment: It's not double integer, it's double float

Comment: @Lundin Basically getting my input integer to be a double value so that when I run my equation, the output can be a double.

Comment: @DAGonz It's not integer input, it's floating point input. Do you understand the difference between integer and floating point?

Comment: I figured it out! Turns out I only had to edit my very last printf statement as: printf("%f") and not printf("%lf")

Comment: @DAGonz That's only because your compiler is so outdated. See my answer below.

Comment: `scanf` expects `%lf` for double (pointer).  But `printf` just use `%f` for double.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The presence of `main()` instead of `int main (void)` means you are using an ancient version of C known as C90, instead of using standard C, since `main()` will only compile cleanly in ancient C90.

C90 did not support `%lf` for `printf` other than as a compiler extension. It only supported `%f` for all floating point types. This could explain why you get weird output. See [Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf).

Solve this by getting an updated compiler and an updated source of learning C.

Comment: I am running a GNU GCC Compiler on the 'latest' download of codeblocks

Comment: @DAGonz The Mingw gcc port that Codeblocks uses isn't necessarily updated since forever - it could be older than gcc 5.0. It's still a somewhat modern compiler, but it defaults to C90. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220462/584518) for a description how you can force it to run modern standard C.

Comment: I compiled this code without problems with `gcc -std=c18`. It gave a warning, but compiled and ran fine.

Comment: @klutt Unlike the OP, so what's your point? `-std=c18` is likely not even available in the default Codeblocks installation. With some luck they updated beyond gcc 5.0 in recent years though.

Comment: @klutt Or if this is another "it compiled fine just with warnings" debate, I'm not having that yet again. After you read C17 5.1.1.3 start using `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not aiming for a debate. I was looking for a clarification. I got it, so thanks. But I think you should edit the answer, because there might be more than me that wonders over this.