# I'm using GNU GCC compiler but code::blocks asking for Cygwin GCC compiler

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, codeblocks

I have installed the code:: blocks from the site where it uses Cygwin compiler.
I have set the GNU compiler as default after installing.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
**The compiler's setup (Cygwin GCC) is invalid, so Code:: Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
  Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
  Do you have a compiler installed?
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->Cygwin GCC->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.

Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\Cygwin/bin/gcc.exe', but failed!
**
```

I have tried the above steps but I'm getting the same error again.

Comment: Well, did you try toolchain executables like it told you? There's a neat auto detect feature there. If you point it to the folder where the gcc compiler is located and click auto detect, the IDE does the rest of the job filling in the paths to compiler, linker etc.

Comment: You can get conflicts if you have multiple instances of gcc installed on the computer. For example Codeblocks comes with Mingw gcc by default, so if you already have Cygwin gcc on the computer and in the `PATH`, the IDE might get confused unless you set all the folder settings correctly. (I've had this very problem myself when I had 32 bit and 64 bit gcc installed at the same time.) This describes how you manually install another gcc than the default one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220462/584518