# Will C automatically free memory with no pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Let's say we run this piece of code in isolation:

```
malloc(1024);
```

Will this result in a memory leak, or will C automatically know to free a pointer with no references?

In other words, can I avoid having to assign it to a pointer?

```
void *p = malloc(1024);
free(p);
```

Comment: What you're talking about is called a *garbage collector*. C (usually) has no such feature. The rule here is simple: if an each call to malloc() (and other *alloc() functions) is matched by exacly one call to free(), then there are no leaks.

Comment: If you don't assign the result of `malloc()` to a variable, how do you access the allocated memory?

Comment: Put another way, why do you want to allocate 1,024 bytes of memory if you're not going to use it?

Comment: The actual application is where I'm nesting several function calls that each return new pointers. Like `bignum *add(bignum *a, bignum *b)`.

Comment: @cchan3141 declare the parameters like `const bignum* const a` and don't change them in the function, then frees are up to the caller

Comment: @cchan3141 alternatively declare your function `void add (bignum* const a, const bignum* const b)` and modify a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any code you write which dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. Freeing the memory is up to *you*.

If you assign a new block of memory to a pointer that currently points to an existing block of memory without first *freeing* the block, you have just overwritten the *starting address* for the original block of memory held by the pointer (violating *rule 1 above*) and you have now lost the ability to free the original block -- which is your memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. The original application was a bunch of nested function calls each returning new pointers, and it seems I must make sure I save the pointer somewhere first before calling each next function.

Comment: @David could you please give me an explanation to my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412495/why-doesnt-valgrind-spot-the-leak-when-program-was-compiled-with-gcc-5-2-0)?

Comment: Sure, but it looks like you got it sorted. My guess would be you `-O2` optimization optimized out the non-use of the allocation resulting in the `0 bytes allocated` message from `valgrind`? Looks like you have an answer now. If you have further questions, just ask.

Comment: I'm still not ok, because the answer and the comments are not showing some reference where I can check if that's true, even if maybe are the right one. Things like use -O0 instead of -O2 doesn't explain Why the leak is not spotted

Comment: OK, let me finish dishes, etc.. and I'll take a closer look. The initial look I took showed `valgrind` reporting `0 bytes allocated` with 5.2, meaning there would be no report of a leak (even if you have code to produce a leak) because there was no memory allocated to begin with -- therefore there can be no leak to report. The differences in the reporting would generally have to do with what was/wasn't optimized out by the compiler. If you never use the memory you allocate, the compiler can just never allocate it to begin with and optimize all that code out. (let me look closer)

Answer (score 5):

It's a memory leak. C does absolutely no memory management for you (except for the C compiler allocating stack space for variables).