# gcc unable to find shared library libisl.so

Tags: gcc, isl

I installed gcc version 5.1 locally on a cluster having OS as CentOS where I dont have root access (so i cant use any commands like '`sudo`'). (The global gcc version installed is 4.4). I also modified the path variable to include the path to my local version at the beginning of the path variable. Before, when I was trying to install boost using the global version, it worked fine. But now, when I try to install boost, it shows the following error:

```
/users/home/head/cmp/soft/sft/gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using ? if Ubuntu (or its family) try this `sudo sudo apt-get install libisl-dev`

Comment: @Michi I am using CentOS.. and I do not have root access, so I cant use sudo...

Comment: Can you run this `ls -al /usr/lib/libisl.so*` ?

Comment: @Michi It shows `ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libisl.so: No such file or directory`..

Comment: what happens if you try to compile with default `GCC` ? `gcc program.c -o program` ?

Comment: @Michi with default gcc it works, but with the local one, I get the same error...

Comment: Your gcc installation is broken -- gcc requires ISL. See the [prerequisites page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) for what is required.

Comment: try `find /users/home/head/cmp/soft/sft/gcc -name 'libisl.so.10'`   and adding the directory it resides in to LD_LIBRARY PATH.

Comment: @Python_user Please try to recompile GCC using this [Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771977/error-building-and-compiling-gcc-5-2-0-from-scratch-on-vortex86dx/32792077#32792077).

Comment: @davmac I am using the command ./bootstrap.sh of the boost installation

Comment: @decltype_auto It shows blank!

Comment: Then ceteris paribus I'd second David Schwartz' hypothesis about a broken gcc install.

Comment: @decltype_auto But the installation proceeded without any issue! No complains at all!

Comment: How did you install *gcc-5.1*, did you compile it from source or did you use `rpm -i` and ignored dependencies?

Comment: @iharob I modified the path variable to include the location of my local gcc at the start.. I followed the tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-from-scratch-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-librari (the answer by user adobe)

Comment: @iharob but i used the --enable-shared options for the dependancies.

Comment: @Python_user I'd doubt that. Better grep your install log for libisl.

Comment: @decltype_auto At the end of the installation, I found the exectables 'gcc' in the bin folder... Is it sufficient for proper installation? Btw, I am retrying the installation.... so my logfile has changed... Moreover, there was a statement by configure "checking for system-wide compatible ISL: yes"... Is this statement sufficient enough to guarantee proper installation? But for some reasons, now the installation is failing.. :(

Comment: @Python_user it seems that you are not doing it right! Did you compile *gcc* from source?, and `--enable-shared` is not for dependencies. It's to compile shared libraries like `libstdc++.so` and other libraries that come with *gcc*.

Comment: @Python_user: well - apparently it is not, or is it.

Comment: @decltype_auto Now, the error is 

`configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/users/home/hranjan/cmp/soft/sft/tar_files_extracted/gcc-5.1.0/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/users/home/hranjan/cmp/soft/sft/tar_files_extracted/gcc-5.1.0/build'
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
`

Comment: @iharob I compiled it from source using the tutorial mentioned in the link...

Comment: You broke you *gcc*, did you change your `PATH` variable? Are you using also `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ensure that `ld.so` can find the libraries? And again, why do you need *gcc-5.1*?

Comment: @iharob yes, i changed my path variable.. and my original gcc is still intact.. when i remove the path to my local gcc from the path variable, i am able to compile my c and c++ programs as usual... I need gcc for a project of mine where i use the command option '--std=c++11'...

Comment: And that's also why `./configure` is not working! You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then to where `libisl.so` is located too. Just like you did with your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @iharob I used the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` mentioned in the answer by user adobe in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-from-scratch-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-librari ... SHould I include the path to libisl in it too? Moreover, my configure is working... the make command is failing.. :(

Comment: Did you install *isl* yourself? And if you did, well yes you should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95233/discussion-between-python-user-and-iharob).

Comment: Why is everyone using adobe's answer at that other question? **IT IS NOT THE RIGHT WAY!** It causes exactly this kind of problem. Ignore that answer and follow my answer there, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10662297/981959

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the instructions at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

Specifically, don't install ISL manually in some non-standard path, because GCC needs to find its shared libraries at run-time.

The simplest solution is to use the `download_prerequisites` script to add the GMP, MPFR, MPC and ISL source code to the GCC source tree, which will cause GCC to build them for you automatically, and link to them statically.

Comment: i am unable to use ftp at the cluster-node on which i am working... so the ./contrib/download_prerequisites is not working... how can i get a workaround this?

Comment: more specifically, i am getting the following error:

`--2015-11-16 18:49:34--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
  (try: 3) => mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2'
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.`

Comment: Look in the script, it's not complicated. Find the URLs, download the packages manually, unpack them in the GCC source tree and create the symlinks that the script would have created.

Comment: using this script is definitely simpler for a newcomer!

Comment: I don't know why people insist on doing it the hard way, when that is harder to do and harder to use the resulting compiler! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. I solved it as follows:

1. Download the source code of isl [available here](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/)
2. Unzip and install:     `./configure && make && make install`
3. `cp /usr/local/lib/libisl*   /usr/lib`

   - Note: a symlink also works:

     $ cd /usr/lib

     $ ln -s  /usr/local/lib/libisl.so.10  libisl.so.10
4. You can do the same in Debian distros:

   apt-get install libisl-dev
5. Adjust the references of shared libs:

   $ cp /usr/local/lib/libisl*   /usr/lib

   - Note: a symlink also works:

     $ cd /usr/lib

     $ ln -s  /usr/local/lib/libisl.so.10  libisl.so.10