# Error doing pip3 install tslearn - command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, python-3.6

when I try to `pip3 install tslearn` on my ElementaryOS (similar to ubuntu) machine I get this error

```
    building 'tslearn.cycc' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tslearn
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/bruno/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c tslearn/cycc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tslearn/cycc.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5p7o5dn8/tslearn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tqrjth8y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5p7o5dn8/tslearn/
```

I've tried the solutions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit?page=1&tab=votes#) but nothing works. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: libisl is missing from your computer, check out some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734143/gcc-unable-to-find-shared-library-libisl-so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc unable to find shared library libisl.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734143/gcc-unable-to-find-shared-library-libisl-so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed it by [installing libisl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668116/7164523), then going into the install location, locating libisl.so, and creating a symlink to point libisl.so.19 to it - by doing `ln -s libisl.so libisl.so.19`