# Cannot compile a simple C program on Elementary distro

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, elementary-os, isl

I'm using elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera (based on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LT) I created a very simple c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf( "Hello World!\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

and executing the following :

```
gcc -o simple simple.c
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try googling the error? There are lots of similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgcc%5D+libisl

Comment: yes nothing helped , this was interesting >
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734143/gcc-unable-to-find-shared-library-libisl-so/55668116#55668116
but the link reported there doesnt work , do you think I need to install isl?

Comment: I'm not sure why this needs `libisl`, that seems like a specialized library.

Comment: in any case trying to install that library I get this:
libisl19 is already the newest version (0.20-N~2~ubuntu18.04.1).

Comment: I think the problem is that it's installed in a different place than GCC expects it.

Comment: Try running `strace  -o trace.txt gcc -o simple simple.c` and then `grep '\.so' trace.txt'` to see the location it actually looks for `libisl.so`. Install `libisl.so` there.

Comment: I have unstallaed the library and reinstalled it and it works now... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with these:

```
sudo apt-get remove libisl19 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```